# assigning to an array in google script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

This is probably an ignorant mistake on my part, but I am trying to assign different values from different column to an array to put in a master sheet. I would like the last column to be equal the the sheet name where the data came from to track it back.

I feel I am close, but when I get to the last column which I want to be the sheet name I get the following error: Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 19, file "combineTOmaster")

This is my code so far. I know the issue is the other column are array[[][]] and the last one is array [][] but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
function getColValues(label,sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var colIndex = getColumnIndex(label, sheetName);
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow() -1;
  if (colIndex > 0 ) { 
    var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRows, 1).getValues();
  } 
  else if (colIndex = "orginalsheet") { 
    var colValues = [];
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows-1;i++) {
      array[i] = sheetName;
    }  
    colValues = array;
  }
      else {
    var colValues = [];
  }
  Logger.log(colValues);
  return colValues;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Should it really be `orgin`? Probably you meant `origin`, i.e. `"originalsheet"`. Then there's the issue that you use `=` as the operator in a conditional check. You must review language fundamentals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: @tehhoch Yes rookie mistake with the = versus ==. That page is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break your function down -

```
// you're passing column header and sheet name, OK
function getColValues(label, sheetName) {
  // getting sheet, OK
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // getting column index, OK
  var colIndex = getColumnIndex(label, sheetName);

  // getting number of rows to collect, OK
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow() - 1;

  // at this point, i assume, variable colIndex is a number, because it should be
  // if label column exists, colIndex will be greater than 0, OK
  if (colIndex > 0) {
    // get values of that column, OK
    var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRows, 1).getValues();
    // colValues will be like this, at this point-
    // [ [value], [value], [value] ... ]

  } else if ((colIndex = 'orginalsheet')) {
    // NOT OK, = sign assigns 'orginalsheet' to colIndex
    // do you wanna assign or compare?
    // to compare, use == sign
    // besides why are you assigning a string value to colIndex ?
    // colIndex should be a number, in my understanding

    // now, what do you wanna do here ?
    var colValues = [];
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows - 1; i++) {
      array[i] = sheetName;
    }
    colValues = array;
    // at his point, colValues is -
    // [sheetName, sheetName, sheetName...]

    // is this correct colValues ?
    // i guess not
    // i think you're trying to use sheetName as a column value for every row
    // if that is the case, do this
    var colValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) colValues.push([sheetName]);
    // now colValues is -
    // [ [sheetName], [sheetName], [sheetName].... ]
    // which you can insert in a sheet as values of a column
  } else {
    var colValues = [];
  }
  Logger.log(colValues);
  return colValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ra89fi  Thank you so much. You lead me to the answer. So mess up 1 was using = and not ==. Mess up two was using colIndex instead of label. Mess up three was not using push. Is there a good resource on push?   Thank you again!!

Below is the final code that worked for me.

```
function getColValues(label,sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var colIndex = getColumnIndex(label, sheetName);
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow() -1;
  if (colIndex > 0 ) { 
    var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRows, 1).getValues();
  } 
  else if (label == "orginalsheet") { 
    var colValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows;i++) {
      colValues.push([sheetName]);
    }  
  }
      else {
    var colValues = [];
  }
  return colValues; 
}
```